# Not able to click on the fields inside the left panel of the page

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have tried below code to click on the fields but getting errors as

```
 "org.openqa.selenium.WeddriverException:unknown error: Element is not clickable at point(138,353). Other element would receive the the click… display: block;>…."
```

Code:

```
WebElement el1 = driver.findElement(By.xapth(".//*@id='BC_PATIENT_COMMUNITY_ENROLLMENT_PATIENT_ID']"));
         JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
         executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click()", el1);
```

UI:
Refer Attached Screenshot
[image]

HTML code:

```
<div id="datatab" class="dijitContentPane panel-content dijitStackContainer-child dijitStackContainer-dijitContentPane" style="padding: 0px; overflow: hidden; left: 0px; top: 0px; height: 154px; width: 258px;" selected="true" data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" widgetid="datatab" title="">
    <div id="datatabpanel" class="tabpanel" style="height: 100%; overflow:hidden; padding: 0px">
        <div class="section-header-outer">
            <div id="fieldlistContainer" style="height: 0px;">
                <div id="fieldlist" class="dojoDndSource dojoDndContainer" data-dojo-attach-point="containerNode" widgetid="fieldlist">
                    <div id="category11545">
                        <div id="field-BC_PATIENT_COMMUNITY_ENROLLMENT_PATIENT_ID" class="category11545 field treenode-leaf-label pentaho-listitem dojoDndItem" fieldid="BC_PATIENT_COMMUNITY_ENROLLMENT_PATIENT_ID" title="BC_PATIENT_COMMUNITY_ENROLLMENT_PATIENT_ID">Patient ID</div>
```

Comment: Is it complete exception log?

Comment: @Andersson -  I have tried below code

Comment: @Andersson -  Please find below exception                                            
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (138, 364). Other element would receive the click: <div tabindex="0" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 88px; width: 1366px; height: 677px; display: block;" aria-hidden="false">...</div>
  (Session info: chrome=55.0.2883.87)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.25.426923 (0390b88869384d6eb0d5d09729679f934aab9eed),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

Answer (score 0):

You are not allowed to click on the div element, rather you can use a workaround to trigger click event by performing "***dragAndDrop operation on the same element***".

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@style='position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 88px; width: 1366px; height: 677px; display: block;']")));
WebElement el1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='field-BC_PATIENT_COMMUNITY_ENROLLMENT_PATIENT_ID']"));
     JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
     executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click()", el1);
```

Comment: I have tried the code and didn't get any error message. But the element is not clicked.

Comment: Are you sure that this `div` is exact element you need to click? are there any child elements?

Comment: Yes, I need to click element in div.                                                             
<div id="field-BC_PATIENT_COMMUNITY_ENROLLMENT_PATIENT_ID" class="category11545 field treenode-leaf-label dojoDndItem pentaho-listitem" fieldid="BC_PATIENT_COMMUNITY_ENROLLMENT_PATIENT_ID" title="BC_PATIENT_COMMUNITY_ENROLLMENT_PATIENT_ID">Patient ID</div>

Comment: Could you try `el1.click();` instead of `JavaScript`?  Any exceptions in this case?

Comment: I tried now and getting same exception message,   org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (138, 300). Other element would receive the click: <div tabindex="0" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 88px; width: 1366px; height: 677px; display: block;" aria-hidden="false">...</div>
  (Session info: chrome=55.0.2883.87)

Answer (score 0):

The `html` you have attached is do not have `id` attribute with value =  `BC_PATIENT_COMMUNITY_ENROLLMENT_PATIENT_ID`. can you just change your `xpath` from -

```
WebElement el1 = driver.findElement(By.xapth(".//*@id='BC_PATIENT_COMMUNITY_ENROLLMENT_PATIENT_ID']"));
```

To

```
WebElement el1 = driver.findElement(By.xapth(".//*[@fieldid='BC_PATIENT_COMMUNITY_ENROLLMENT_PATIENT_ID']"));

//or

WebElement el1 = driver.findElement(By.xapth(".//*[@id='field-BC_PATIENT_COMMUNITY_ENROLLMENT_PATIENT_ID']"));
```